# Firing Events not working in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to call fwre-sel-region_id's change method when page loads. Normally this method get called after a select id's option select is changed. This doesn't work form me, since the select id only has one valid option.So I would like for it to get called after I change the select id through javascript. I was sucessfully in changing the select id's index now I would like for it call fwre-sel-region_id's change method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    if ($('fwre-sel-region_id')) {
        $('fwre-sel-region_id').addEvent('change', function() {
            $('fwre-sel-city_id').options.length = 0;
            if (this.value == '(add-value)') return;
            var img = new Element('img', {
                'id': 'fwre-wait-region',
                'style' : 'margin:0;padding:0;',
                'src': '/administrator/components/com_fwrealestatelight/assets/images/spinner.gif'
            });
            img.inject($('fwre-sel-city_id'), 'after');
             new Request.JSON({
                url: '/properties?format=raw&task=loadDictionary',
                onSuccess: function(obj) {
                    if ($('fwre-wait-region')) $('fwre-wait-region').dispose();
                    if (obj.msg) {
                        alert(obj.msg);
                    } else if (obj.data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
                            var op = new Element('option', {
                                'value': obj.data[i].id
                            });
                            op.inject($('fwre-sel-city_id'));
                            op.innerHTML = obj.data[i].name;
                        }
                    }
                    $('fwre-sel-city_id').fireEvent('change');
                }
            }).get({'parent_id':$('fwre-sel-region_id').value,'dname':'city_id'});
        });
    }
}, 500);
```

I'm trying to call the method above with this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.addEvent('load', function(){
     var country = document.id('fwre-sel-country_id');
     var region = document.id('fwre-sel-region_id');
     $(country).selectedIndex = 1;
    region.fireEvent('change');
    });
    </script>
```

My script is both below the script in the file and html though when region.fireEvent('change'); is executed it doesn't make it's way back up to the first method. Why is this happening?

Comment: why the ambiguous `setTimeout` when adding the event handler? use `window.addEvent('domready', fn);` when you need to bind to dom events. you can have multiple domready bindings but order will matter here. `load` when cached is primed and things are cached may well trigger before the 500ms delay you have, meaning no event will be cached. you can still do `console.log(region.retrieve('events'));` to check if the event is attached before you `fireEvent`

Comment: also, you should use `.get('value')` or `.getSelected()` which is api. as well as `.set('value')`, stick to mootools api and not direct object props.

Comment: I honestly don't know why there's an ambiguous setTimout Event. I didn't write this. I didn't write the first event.